# My script keeps returning IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

So part of the script I'm currently working on is a list consisting of several words. I want Python to loop over the words one by one and reverse each word.

I tried to do it this way:

Let's assume I input 'Hello world this is a python script'

```
def main():
    print()
    ptext = input('Please input the plaintext...')
    ctext = ''
    plist=ptext.split(' ')
    for item in plist:
        i = len(item)
        while i>=0:
            ctext = ctext + str(item)[i]
            i=i-1
    print()
    print('The ciphertext is: ',ctext.lower()) #Print out the ciphertext
    print()
```

But i keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#137>", line 2, in <module>
    print((item)[i],end =(' '))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I clearly told the script that `i=len(item)`, so how can it be out of range??

My best and only guess is that it's taking the length of a word like 'world' which is 5 and use it on a word like 'is' or 'a'. Is it possible to tell Python to take the length of each word only? I couldn't figure a way to do it.

Comment: Python list indexing is zero-based.  If a list has five items, the valid indexes are `item[0]` through `item[4]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first index of a string is 0 and the last is “the length - 1”. So you'd need to set `i = len(item) - 1`, because in the first iteration you basically try to access `str(item)[len(item)]`.

Apart from that the `str()` call should not be necessary, so just `item[i]`.

Also note that if you want to “reverse” a string you can actually do `reversed_string = original_string[::-1]`. The `[::-1]` says that it should return the string but go from the end and step to the beginning one character.

Comment: Big thanks for taking the time to answer ! And your suggestion works

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
ctext = ctext + str(item)[i]
```

with:

```
ctext = ctext + str(item[i])
#                        ^ access index of item
```

And, initialize `i` as:

```
i = len(item) - 1  # because index starts with 0, and can be retrieved till `len - 1`
```

Comment: `item[i]` is still out of range, because `i = len(item)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Yes. You are sharp watcher ;). Updated it.

Comment: Better yet, remove `str` completely.

Comment: John Gordon & anonymous you guys are awesome!! big Thanks! It's working now!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: If you check the logic, in actual OP is printing just the lowered case version of the string in took as input without (space) in revrsed order. `print ptext.lower().replace(' ', '')[::-1]` is enough. So skipped refactoring part

Comment: @anonymous The string is actually reversed, but that should work as well: `ptext.lower().replace(' ', '')[::-1]` (also it should be `ptext`). (Oh you already edited the reverse part)

Comment: @scripter:  [Accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped, for others taking reference for the same problem in future. :-)

Comment: I don't know how to do that